# Elmah error logging on azure storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, paging, elmah, elmah.mvc

I am using Elmah for logging error in my asp.net MVC application. This is added from nuget. I am using Azure table storage for logging the exceptions.

The Elmah is working fine and logging exceptions. The only problem is it show only first 15 errors. Even if i click on 50 or 100, it still shows the recent 15 errors.

Did anyone faced the same problem? A solution with a sample code will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Which ErrorLog implementation are you using?

Comment: Link? ELMAH doesn't provide Azure error log out of the box, right? Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: is it this http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/08/using-elmah-in-windows-azure-with-table-storage/ ?

Comment: You should probably ask the author of that NuGet package. Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Can you send me a link how you integrated ELMAH for Azure table storage.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Azure Table Storage does not support an efficient way to get a count of the records. Consequently, the count returned from `override int GetErrors(int pageIndex, int pageSize, IList errorEntryList)` is what is deemed as the total.

You can however modify the query string and page manually through Elmah, i.e *elmah.axd?**page=3**&size=100*